# Why is android plugin 3.2.1 using aapt2 in the cache instead of using my build-tools?

Tags: android, centos6, gradle-plugin, aapt2

**Info:**

> Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
>   Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux.jar
>   AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux.jar/28466e2cbc873eea3f650b3c015e2502/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux/aapt2: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux.jar/28466e2cbc873eea3f650b3c015e2502/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux/aapt2)

**What have done:**

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.14.tar.gz
tar zxvf glibc-2.14.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.14
mkdir build
cd build
../configure –prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14
make -j4
sudo make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib

build-tools/28.0.3/aapt2
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib && "$0"_ $@
```

**Question:**

My system has been downloaded and configured with build-tools, but still without aapt2 in build-tools

Answer (score 1):

The Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0-alpha11 and newer (that includes your version of 3.2.1) doesn't use AAPT2 from the build tools anymore due to the infrequent releases of build tools.

Instead AGP gets AAPT2 from Google maven (this is why you need to have the "google()" dependency in your build.gradle). Thanks to this, AGP can come with a fresh version of AAPT2 with recent fixes and features without waiting a long time for the next version of build tools to come out.

Comment: Can't it be built under centOs 6? Because the build requires lib 2.14, but centOs 6 is only 2.12, I can manually download 2.14 and then specify the aapt2 environment variable. But now every time you need to manually download google aapt2 can not specify lib 2.14