# Problem with AAPT2 - AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: �: not found

Tags: android, gradle, compilation, gradlew, aapt2

I'm trying to compile an android app in a raspberry. When I use `gradlew assembleRelease` I get this error. I don't find anything about it on internet...

```
((



AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4396707ed6be3225c88a086a05435f8/transformed/aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux/aapt2: 1: �@��@8
> :app:mergeReleaseResources                                                                                                                                                                 @#!@@@����T�T�: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4396707ed6be3225c88a086a05435f8/transformed/aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux/aapt2: 1: �: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4396707ed6be3225c88a086a05435f8/transformed/aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux/aapt2: 1: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4396707ed6be3225c88a086a05435f8/transformed/aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux/aapt2: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4396707ed6be3225c88a086a05435f8/transformed/aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux/aapt2: 1: �@��@8
> :app:mergeReleaseResources                                                                                                                                                                 @#!@@@����T�T�: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4396707ed6be3225c88a086a05435f8/transformed/aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux/aapt2: 1: �: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4396707ed6be3225c88a086a05435f8/transformed/aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux/aapt2: 1: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4396707ed6be3225c88a086a05435f8/transformed/aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux/aapt2: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4396707ed6be3225c88a086a05435f8/transformed/aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux/aapt2: 1: �@��@8
> :app:mergeReleaseResources                                                                                                                                                                 @#!@@@����T�T�: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4396707ed6be3225c88a086a05435f8/transformed/aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux/aapt2: 1: �: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4396707ed6be3225c88a086a05435f8/transformed/aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux/aapt2: 1: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4396707ed6be3225c88a086a05435f8/transformed/aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux/aapt2: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
```

Can someone help me? :(

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Google does not provide `aapt2` binary for `arm` devices. You can build your yourself, or use [this repository](https://github.com/revanced/aapt2/), which contains workflow to build it with Github Actions. Then you can replace `aapt2` binary under `/root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4396707ed6be3225c88a086a05435f8/transformed/aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux/` (path from error) with binary matching your architecture.

Keep in mind, that Android Gradle Plugin [does not use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53562636/11403731) `aapt2` binary from sdk's build tools, so we are replacing it in gradle caches directory, not build tools directory.